# Two Dimensional Hodge Decomposition

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, waveguide

In deriving the equation governing propagation of wave in a wave guide, a specific form of Hodge decomposition theorem is used. The Hodge decomposition theorem applied in two dimensions allows us to write a smooth vector field $\vec V$ on a bounded region $S$ with boundary $C$, such that the component of the vector field tangential to boundary $\vec V_{\parallel}|_C=0$ vanishes, as follows
$$\vec V=\nabla A+\hat z\times\nabla B+\vec X$$
where $\hat z$ is orthogonal to $S$, and $A|_C=0$, $B|_C=(\hat n\cdot\nabla B)|_C=0$ (Dirichlet and Neumann B.C. respectively).
Given
$$\nabla^2A=\nabla\cdot\vec V$$
and
$$\nabla^2B=-\nabla\cdot(\hat z\times\vec V)$$
and define
$$\vec X=\vec V-\nabla A-\hat z\times\nabla B$$
I wonder how to prove $\vec X$ is harmonic, in a sense that it satisfy the Laplace's equation $\nabla^2\vec X=0$? I argued

Since
$$\nabla^2\vec X=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec X)-\nabla\times(\nabla\times\vec X)$$
we can show
$$\begin{align}\nabla(\nabla\cdot \vec X)=&\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec V-\nabla^2A-\nabla\cdot(\hat z\times\nabla B))\\=&-(\nabla B\cdot(\nabla\times\hat z)-\hat z\cdot(\nabla\times \nabla B ))\\=&0\end{align}$$
to get the second line, the Poisson's equation is used, and the third line follows from $\nabla\times\hat z=0$ and the curl of gradient is $0$
then we have to show the following equation equals $0$.
$$\begin{align}\nabla\times(\nabla\times\vec X)=&\nabla\times(\nabla\times(\vec V-\nabla A-\hat z\times\nabla B))\\=&\nabla\times(\nabla\times \vec V-\nabla\times \nabla A-(\hat z(\nabla\cdot\nabla B)-\nabla B(\nabla\cdot\hat z)+\nabla (B\cdot\nabla)\hat z-(\hat z\cdot\nabla)\nabla B))\end{align}$$
At this stage, I don't know how to proceed anymore, except for the identity $\nabla\times\nabla\times \vec V=\nabla(\nabla\cdot \vec V)-\nabla^2\vec V$. Can someone help me to fill the missing steps and show $\nabla\times(\nabla\times\vec X)$is indeed zero?

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\nabla \times \hat z = 0$, $\nabla \cdot \hat z = 0$, $(Y\cdot \nabla)\hat z = 0$ for any vector field $Y$.

Also, we can assume that $(\hat z\cdot \nabla) B = 0$, because we are only interested on the value of $B$ on $S$.

Using all this, we can compute :
\begin{align}
\nabla\times X &= \nabla \times V - \nabla\times (\nabla A) -\nabla\times (\hat z\times \nabla B) \\
&= \nabla \times V -\hat z \nabla^2B \\
&= \nabla\times V + \hat z\nabla \cdot (\hat z\times V) \\
&= \nabla\times V - \hat z\hat z \cdot( \nabla \times V) 
\end{align}

Then :
\begin{align}
\nabla \times (\nabla \times X) &= \nabla \times (\nabla \times V)- \nabla\times (\hat z\hat z\cdot(\nabla\times V))\\
&= \nabla \times (\nabla \times V) + \hat z\times \nabla (\hat z \cdot (\nabla\times V)) \\
&=\nabla \times (\nabla \times V) +\hat z\times (\hat  z\times (\nabla \times (\nabla\times V)))
\end{align}
Since $\nabla\times (\nabla\times V)$ is orthogonal to $\hat z$, we hat :
$$\hat z\times (\hat  z\times (\nabla \times (\nabla\times V)) = -\nabla \times (\nabla\times V)$$
and :
$$\nabla \times (\nabla \times V)= 0$$